# Cycles material with bump and image texture - scale only the bump map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scale, bump

What I'm trying to achieve is a smaller/finer bump pattern in the material while the image should remain at its current size. I tried scaling the UV map but then the image texture is scaled the same way.

Or let me know if you have a good material setup for wallpaper that also allows for an image texture.

Cheers!

[image: the material setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *Mapping* node to adjust the scale of the texture. It would be placed between the connection of the *Texture Coordinate* node and the *Image Texture* node.

[image]

Comment: that's it! thanks for the quick fix :)

Comment: @SashaC. You may want to switch the mode from *Point* to *Texture*, forgot to do that in the screenshot. It will work either way, but the scaling factor is reciprocal.

Answer (score 0):

Rjg gave a solution. You can also create 2 different *Input* > *UV Map* nodes, one for the image, one for the bump. Scale the second differently in the *UV/Image Editor*.

[image]